# fetching multiple image from urls

Tags: android, inputstream, urlconnection

I have an application which allow to download 3 images and show them into a gallery
In order to do this , i use a thread in order to download the images and a handler in order to put the images into the gallery

The problem is that the images are not displayed(imageviews are empty) into the gallery (even if i see 3 imageview for my 3 images)

I do not know if this is because the connection is very slow (I develop on a mobile) or if it's because the ui is displayed before images are downloaded

Thank you very much for your help

```
public class ChoiceLanguage extends Activity {
    private TextView nomLangue;

    private ArrayList<Language> listeLangues;
    private ArrayList<String> listImages;
    private Gallery gallery;
    private String URL="******************";
    private Drawable mNoImage;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ImageView imgView = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.choice_language);


        listeLangues= getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("listeLangues");
        listImages=buildListImages();


        gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.galleryImg);

        gallery.setAdapter(new AddImgAdp(this));

        gallery.setSpacing(10);


        gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {            

                 System.out.println("URL "+ listImages.get(position) );
            }
        });


}

    private InputStream openHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = null;

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        in=conn.getInputStream();
        return in;
    }

    private Bitmap downloadImage( ImageView iView, String url) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis ;
        try {

            in = openHttpConnection(url);
            bis= new BufferedInputStream(in, 8192);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            in.close();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;

    }


    private ArrayList<String> buildListImages() {
        ArrayList<String> listImg = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Language l : listeLangues) {
            listImg.add(URL+l.getImagePath());

        }   

        return listImg;
    }

    public class AddImgAdp extends BaseAdapter {
        int GalItemBg;
        private Context cont;

        public AddImgAdp(Context c) {
            cont = c;
            TypedArray typArray = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.GalleryTheme);
            GalItemBg = typArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.GalleryTheme_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
            typArray.recycle();
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return listImages.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                imgView = new ImageView(cont);
            } else {
                imgView = (ImageView)convertView;
            }

            ThreadDownload progressDl= new ThreadDownload(position);
            progressDl.start();

            imgView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 150));
            imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imgView.setBackgroundResource(GalItemBg);

            return imgView;
        }
    }
    private class SetImg extends Handler {

        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
    private class ThreadDownload extends Thread {
        SetImg img= new SetImg();
        int position ;
        public ThreadDownload(int position)
        {
            super();
            this.position=position;
        }
        public void run() {
         bitmap = downloadImage(imgView,listImages.get(position));      
         img.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
       }



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of SmartImageView, it is a drop-in replacement for Android’s standard ImageView which additionally allows images to be loaded from URLs or the user’s contact address book. Images are cached to memory and to disk for super fast loading.

https://github.com/loopj/android-smart-image-view

Comment: .Thank you very much . It works great but for some reason , the gallery freeze and block when i try to change image. This problem wasn t here with previous imageview. Do u know why ? Thank you